# Firebase Flutter iOS initialization issue

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, plist

Hi I am getting following issue while I am trying to initialze firebase.

> Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist"
> file to the project?

My code is:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

I am using separate Google Service Info Plist for development and production.

[image]

So I am using following script in Xcode under **Target** > **Build Phase** > **Run New Script Phase** to copy the plist to main directory.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/prod/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Production plist copied"

elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then

cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/Firebase/dev/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"

echo "Development plist copied"
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you add place in code where you get this exception?

Comment: you cp file to `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"`, but make sure `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"` is in your iOS project.

Comment: @iwpz.. It doesn't work when I change the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some default GoogleService-Info.plist into `${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist` (best option would be the dev one)

After you start building, your script will override that one.

XCode project have to know that *GoogleService-Info.plist* exists in project, your script is about overriding it's content

Answer (score 0):

open your /ios/Runner/Runner.xcworkspace with xcode,
then add the Google-info.plist to this file (click right and choose add file to Runner) ,
then choose the file and don't forget to check the option of copy items and you are donne.